# PHP with MySQL query not returning expected results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to select records (for search functionality) in my table where the month is static and other columns vary.

Below is the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM issue 
WHERE month = "Apr 2019" 
    AND issue LIKE "%ekh%" 
    OR issue_type LIKE "%ekh%" 
    OR facility LIKE "%ekh%" 
    OR issue_id LIKE "%ekh%" 
    OR priority LIKE "%ekh%" 
ORDER BY issue_id DESC
```

This is rather returning all rows that satisfy the like clauses, even when month isnt = "Apr 2019".

Comment: Put all the `like` statements inside parentheses, so you have `month="XX" and (issues like "XX" etc)`.

Comment: Fix your parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In algebra, the `AND` operation is done before the `OR` operation. This is the same rule in your `WHERE` clause.

You can fix this with parentheses like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM issue
WHERE month = "Apr 2019"
    AND (issue LIKE "%ekh%"
        OR issue_type LIKE "%ekh%"
        OR facility LIKE "%ekh%"
        OR issue_id LIKE "%ekh%"
        OR priority LIKE "%ekh%")
ORDER BY issue_id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

When mysql hits first `or` it automatically returns everything because `or something is true`. Therefore you should use parentheses:

```
SELECT *
FROM issue
WHERE month = "Apr 2019" AND
(issue like "%ekh%" OR
 issue_type like "%ekh%" OR
 facility like "%ekh%" OR
 issue_id like "%ekh%" OR
 priority like "%ekh%")
ORDER BY issue_id DESC
```